# kernel and user space sync

Tags: caching, linux-kernel

I have memory area mapped to user space with `do_mmap_pgoff()` and `remap_pfn_range()` and I have the same area mapped to kernel with `ioremap()`.

When I write to this area from user space and then read from kernel space I see that not all bytes was written to memory area.

When I write from user space then read from user and after that read from kernel everything fine. Reading from user space pushing changes made previously.

I understand that cache or buffer exist between kernel and user spaces. I understand that I need to implement some flush-invalidate or buffer dump to memory area.

I tried to make this VMA uncached with `pgprot_uncached()`, I tried to implement outer cache range flush-invalidate, VMA cache range flush, VMA tlb range flush but it all dont work as I expected. All flush-inval operations just clears memory area but I need to apply changes made from user space. Using uncached memory slows up the process of data transferring.

How to do that synchronization between user and kernel correctly?

Comment: Is it MMIO?! Why and how you are trying to use it in user space? Perhaps you need UIO framework.

Comment: How and why I use it in user space it is wery long story. This is fine.
Reading from same memory region from user space pushing changes to real memory somehow. I just need to find what is responsible for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same question as you.

I use a shared memory region to pass data between kernel and user space. In kernel, I directly use physical address to access data. In user space, I open `/dev/mem` and mmap it to read/write.

And problem comes: **When I write data to address A from user space, the kernel may not receive the data, and even covers data in A with it's previous value.** I think CPU cache may cause this problem.

Here is my solution:

I open `/dev/mem` like this:

```c
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
```

NOT this:

```c
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
```

And problem solved.